# Anyone sucessfully installed pywafo for Python 3 under windows OS?

Tags: python

I've tried: 
pip install wafo
pip install wafo==0.3.1

The instructions of readme provide a 2 step installation process but it fails on the first one.

I am using windows 10 and python 3.6.1.

Right now, rather than assistance to make it work I would just like to know if I'm on a fools errand or if its actually possible to install wafo for python under configurations like I have.

Appreciate any reply.

Answer (score 1):

this is probably a little late in the day to answer. I have a wafo "superficially working" on windows 10 with python 3.7.1: however, so far I have only accessed the wave spectrum models. The recipe I used was

1. clone the repo
2. pip install 2to3
3. navigate to the cloned folder
4. 2to3 . -w
5. copy folder to src/wafo folder to site-packages/wafo
6. Open cmd.exe or something better e.g. ConEmu
7. Assuming your python.exe is in your PATH. type ... python -c "import wafo"
8. Then address each problem in turn...

There aren't many problems to address if all you need are the wave spectrum models. It took me an hour to hack the source code to access these. If you need to access the whole suite of functionality, continue the approach. You may need to recompile the c-libraries if they are needed.

Sorry I can't provide a comprehensive list of the changes I made to get wafo to import. Here are the ones I remember

- It will complain about "import scipy.lib.six". Change to "import six" (install it)
- It will complain about scipy's piecewisepolynomial. Change to PPoly
- It will complain some version checks ... set to True as your module versions are no-doubt much newer than the versions 5 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

I have a fork of the official WAFO repo that I use, having converted it to python 3 a year or so ago. I haven't updated it in a while and haven't tested all the functionality, but anyone still looking for this is welcome to try using:

```
pip install https://github.com/JohnCHarrington/pywafo.git
```